# WebInvoke with UriTemplate with empty strings

Tags: asp.net, wcf, webmethod, uritemplate

How does the WebInvokeAttribute and UriTemplate resolver behave when supplied with empty strings in placeholders at runtime?

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675245.aspx) doesn't seem to cover this.

In some inherited code, I'm getting situations where the methods are not being resolved properly when empty strings are passed.  There is no obvious conflict with other web methods.

Thanks!

Update:

In a UriTemplate such as: `"/{x}/{y}?z={z}"`, what is the behavior if some or all of the values are provided as "" empty strings, but the delimiters remain, `"/17/?z="`, `"//apple?z="`, `"//?z=%20"`, `"//?z="`.  Also, by standard, are browsers allowed to *clean up* URIs before sending them?

Answer (score -2):

The empty string means that the URI for the operation is located at the same address as the endpoint - see the example below for more information.

```
public class StackOverflow_6267866
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest1
    {
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "")]
        string EchoString(string text);
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest2
    {
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        int Add(int x, int y);
    }
    public class Service : ITest1, ITest2
    {
        public string EchoString(string text)
        {
            return text;
        }

        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
    static void SendPostRequest(string uri, string contentType, string body)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = contentType;
        byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
        req.GetRequestStream().Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
        req.GetRequestStream().Close();

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", resp.ProtocolVersion, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
        foreach (string headerName in resp.Headers.AllKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", headerName, resp.Headers[headerName]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(respStream).ReadToEnd());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("  *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*  ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest1), new WebHttpBinding(), "ITest1").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ITest2), new WebHttpBinding(), "ITest2").Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        SendPostRequest(baseAddress + "/ITest1", "application/json", "\"hello world\"");
        SendPostRequest(baseAddress + "/ITest1/", "application/json", "\"hello world\"");
        SendPostRequest(baseAddress + "/ITest2", "application/json", "{\"x\":123,\"y\":456}");
        SendPostRequest(baseAddress + "/ITest2/", "application/json", "{\"x\":123,\"y\":456}");

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not empty string for the whole uri, empty string values at runtime.